# How to extract integers within curly braces in R?

Tags: r, regex, perl, stringr

I have a sample data frame `act` with two variables that looks somewhat like this:

```
   activity_id          activity_ids
1          227 {227,32,33,34,35,252}
2           32 {227,32,33,34,35,252}
3           33 {227,32,33,34,35,252}
4           34 {227,32,33,34,35,252}
5           35 {227,32,33,34,35,252}
6          252 {227,32,33,34,35,252}
7          227 {227,32,33,34,35,252}
8           32 {227,32,33,34,35,252}
9           33 {227,32,33,34,35,252}
10          34 {227,32,33,34,35,252}
```

`activity_id` is the integer variable and `activity_ids` is the character variable.

Now, I want to add a new boolean variable say `last_activity` which returns true or false by checking if the value of `activity_id` is the last number among the set of numbers within curly braces of `activity_ids` variable. For this sample data, this new variable `last_activity` should return `TRUE` only for the 6th row (since 252 is the last number) and return `FALSE` for all other rows. Also, in this sample data, `activity_ids` variable has 6 numbers within braces. It could have any number of values within braces. So, I'd need a code that could be generalized for any number of values.

Thanks!

Comment: `!rowSums(adist(paste0(dat$activity_id,"}"),dat$activity_ids,partial = T))`

Answer (score 3):

Using a base R option, `sub` can work here:

```
df <- data.frame(activity_id=c(227, 252),
                 activity_ids=c("{227,32,33,34,35,252}", "{227,32,33,34,35,252}"))

df$last_activity <- df$activity_id == sub(".*,(\\d+)\\}$", "\\1", df$activity_ids)
df

      activity_id          activity_ids last_activity
1             227 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
2             252 {227,32,33,34,35,252}          TRUE
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

I just realised that the original approach has an issue when the `activity_ids` contain extra bit of information. For example,

```
df$activity_ids[6] <- "{227,32,33,34,35,2521}"

mapply(function(x, y) grepl(y, tail(x, 1), fixed = TRUE),
       strsplit(df$activity_ids, ","), df$activity_id)

#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

would still return `TRUE` which is wrong.

To overcome that we can instead extract the numeric part of the last value and then compare it with `activity_id`

```
mapply(function(x, y) y == sub("[^0-9]","",tail(x, 1)),
       strsplit(df$activity_ids, ","), df$activity_id)

#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

df$activity_ids[6] <- "{227,32,33,34,35,2521}"

mapply(function(x, y) y == sub("[^0-9]","",tail(x, 1)),
      strsplit(df$activity_ids, ","), df$activity_id)

#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

**Original Answer**

A non-regex option would be splitting the string on "," and take the last value using `tail` and check if it exists in `activity_id` with `grepl`.

```
df$last_activity <- mapply(function(x, y) grepl(y, tail(x, 1), fixed = TRUE),
                    strsplit(df$activity_ids, ","), df$activity_id)

#   activity_id          activity_ids last_activity
#1          227 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
#2           32 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
#3           33 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
#4           34 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
#5           35 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
#6          252 {227,32,33,34,35,252}          TRUE
#7          227 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
#8           32 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
#9           33 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
#10          34 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex approach would be to extract the last number from the string using `stri_extract_last_regex` from `stringi` package and compare it with `activity_id`

```
library(stringi)
df$activity_id == stri_extract_last_regex(df$activity_ids, "[0-9]+")

#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```
transform(dat,s=Vectorize(grepl)(paste0(activity_id,"}"),activity_ids))
   activity_id          activity_ids     s
1          227 {227,32,33,34,35,252} FALSE
2           32 {227,32,33,34,35,252} FALSE
3           33 {227,32,33,34,35,252} FALSE
4           34 {227,32,33,34,35,252} FALSE
5           35 {227,32,33,34,35,252} FALSE
6          252 {227,32,33,34,35,252}  TRUE
7          227 {227,32,33,34,35,252} FALSE
8           32 {227,32,33,34,35,252} FALSE
9           33 {227,32,33,34,35,252} FALSE
10          34 {227,32,33,34,35,252} FALSE
```

For faster computation use the package `stringi`

```
stringi::stri_detect_fixed(dat$activity_ids,paste0(dat$activity_id,"}"))
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `apply()` column-wise in base `R`:

```
cols <- c('activity_id', 'activity_ids')
df$last_activity <- apply(df[cols], 1, function(col) {
  x <- unlist(strsplit(col['activity_ids'], "[{},]"))
  return(col['activity_id'] == x[length(x)])
})
```

Or using `mapply()`:

```
df$last_activity <- mapply(function(x,y) {x == y[length(y)]}, 
       x = df$activity_id, 
       y = strsplit(df$activity_ids, "[{},]")
)
```

Both will yield

```
   activity_id          activity_ids last_activity
1          227 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
2           32 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
3           33 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
4           34 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
5           35 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
6          252 {227,32,33,34,35,252}          TRUE
7          227 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
8           32 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
9           33 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
10          34 {227,32,33,34,35,252}         FALSE
11         212              somejunk         FALSE
```